# Tank Auth http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/auth Error

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

This is my first time using authentication library. I followed [this post](http://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/setting-up-tank-auth-2/) to install tank auth. But there is something wrong at http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/auth when I try to access it. It gives me some lines in the page:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: require_once(phpass-0.1/PasswordHash.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: libraries/Tank_auth.php
>
> Line Number: 3

I tried to edit the third line of ~/codeigniter/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php and nothing good happened. I'm sure that PasswordHash.php exists in phpass-0.1 directory.

Could anyone help me or shed some light?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the `phpass-0.1/PasswordHash.php` file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitely in that the file `PasswordHash.php` cannot be found in this line of code:

```
 require_once(phpass-0.1/PasswordHash.php)
```

Confirm the file exists in the location you think it does, and I hope you are using quotes:

```
require_once('file.php');
```

Comment: I'm sure there is PasswordHash.php in the phpass-0.1 directory.

This is what is written on the third line of Tank_auth.php:
require_once('phpass-0.1/PasswordHash.php');

Comment: Confirmed quotes? If yes, confirm you have read permissions at the directory

Comment: ahhhh... you're right
I tried '$ chmod 701 phpass-0.1' and it works like a charm.

Thank you @xbonez. You save my day.

Comment: glad to have helped. If you could accept the answer (by clicking on the check mark) that would be great